# Change State without using ui-sref in Angular 2 using ui-router-ng2.(Angular2 & UI-Router-ng2)

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

**How to use $state.go() in angular 2**.I want to change state based on some event of for that I am trying to do it in plnk.Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JS9vx6)  which is not working at all.

Code :

```
/** imports */

    import {NgModule, Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {UIRouterModule ,   Transition } from "ui-router-ng2";
    import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

    /** Components */

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
      <a uiSref="hello" uiSrefActive="active">Hello</a>
      <a (click)=hello() uiSrefActive="active">About</a>

      <ui-view></ui-view>
      `
    })
    export class App { 
      constructor(trans: Transition) { 
        //this.$state = trans.router.stateService;
      }

      hello(){
        console.log("hello clicked");
        //this.$state.go('about');

      }
    }

    @Component({  
      template: '<h3>Hello world!</h3>' 
    })
    class Hello { }

    @Component({ 
      template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>' 
    })
    class About { }


    /** States */

    let helloState = { name: 'hello', url: '/hello',  component: Hello }; 
    let aboutState = { name: 'about', url: '/about',  component: About };

    /** Root Application NgModule */

    @NgModule({
      imports: [ 
        BrowserModule,
        UIRouterModule.forRoot({ states: [ helloState, aboutState ], useHash: true }),

      ],
      declarations: [ App, Hello, About ],
      bootstrap: [ App ]
    })
    class RootAppModule {}

    /** Angular 2 bootstrap */

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(RootAppModule);
```

I want that when user successfully logged in on success I want to change state. I was doing in Angular 1.6 using $state.go(). I am not able to figure same out with angular 2 and Ui router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the changes

/** imports */

```
    import {NgModule, Component} from '@angular/core';
    **import { TargetState, StateService } from 'ui-router-core';**
    import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

    /** Components */

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
      <a uiSref="hello" uiSrefActive="active">Hello</a>
      <a (click)=hello() uiSrefActive="active">About</a>

      <ui-view></ui-view>
      `
    })
    export class App { 
      constructor(**private $state: StateService**) { 

      }

      hello(){
        console.log("hello clicked");
        this.$state.go('about');

      }
    }

    @Component({  
      template: '<h3>Hello world!</h3>' 
    })
    class Hello { }

    @Component({ 
      template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>' 
    })
    class About { }


    /** States */

    let helloState = { name: 'hello', url: '/hello',  component: Hello }; 
    let aboutState = { name: 'about', url: '/about',  component: About };

    /** Root Application NgModule */

    @NgModule({
      imports: [ 
        BrowserModule,
        UIRouterModule.forRoot({ states: [ helloState, aboutState ], useHash: true }),

      ],
      declarations: [ App, Hello, About ],
      bootstrap: [ App ]
    })
    class RootAppModule {}

    /** Angular 2 bootstrap */

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(RootAppModule);
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. Here is the working plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/VjRe0IXUs0SU8cG5utNf

Answer (score 0):

Import the router in app like this

```
    import { TargetState, StateService } from 'ui-router-core';
```

And in constructor use the stateservice like below code:

```
constructor(appConfig: AppConfigService,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private $state: StateService
  )

this.$state.go(state, params, options)
```

Comment: I am using UI-Router not Router of Angular 2. Will it work?

Comment: Its open for public. There is some error I am facing there. Can you show me it in plunker? Thanks in advance